# How to commit multiple nested values that are supposed to be in the same Vuex Store object and that are not mapped to the store object?

Tags: json, vue.js, nested, vuex, v-model

How would it work if I want to commit the input value and the selected options in the Vuex store (without the "label" string so that the object I send matches my Vuex store object) ?

Template

```
                <div v-for="(section, indexSections) in sections" :key="indexSections">                                
                    <div v-for="(item, indexItem) in section" :key="indexItem">                      
                      <div>

                        <select
                          v-model="sections[indexSection][indexItem].options"                        
                          :options="selectOptions"
                        ></select>

                        <b-input
                          type="text"
                          v-model="sections[indexSection][indexItem].sectionItem"                                                   
                        ></b-input>
                        <b-button @click="removeItem({section,item})"/>  

                      </div>
                    </div>      

                  <div">
                    <b-button @click="addNewItem(section)"/>                                        
                    <b-button @click="addNewSection"/>
                  </div>

                </div>
```

Data

```
selectOptions: [
        {
          options: { option1: true, option2: true },
          label: "First"
        },
        {
          options: { option1: false, option2: true },
          label: "Second"
        }      
      ]
```

Computed

```
Computed: {

sections: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.sections;
      }
    }
```

Store

```
sections: [
                [{
                    sectionItem: "",
                    options: {
                        strict: true,
                        includes: true
                    }

                }]
            ],
```

Comment: Right off the bat, a `select` tag does not have an `options` attribute. You need to put a `v-for` on an `option` tag within your `select`. Also, your `sections` property should just be an array of objects, not an array or arrays.

Comment: If I need to pass multiple sections where each section has multiple items, then it needs to be an array of arrays. It's not so unusual from what I read

Comment: And a select CAN have an options attribute, just like it is in a multiselect component (https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-option-groups)

Comment: vue-multiselect is a custom component. That component can accept an options attribute. Your example is using a select element. There is no options attribute on a select element.

Comment: It's my mistake in the stackoverflow question. I do use vue-multiselect in the project

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `v-model` in order to change the Vuex state, that is what the mutations are for.

`v-model` is just syntatic sugar and handles the event and updating of values. You have to implement `v-on:change` yourself and call a Vuex mutation to set the selected option.

Your `selectOptions` array looks unusual. Usually you just have a `label` and a `value` for options. The `value` is the selected value when the user selects an option.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <select @change="onChange">
            <option v-for="option in selectOptions" :value="option.value">
                {{ option.label }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            selectOptions: [
                //...
            ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(event) {
            this.$store.commit('setSelectedOption', event.target.value);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but you CAN use v-model with mutations through get/set : https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html. I do it on another project and it works perfectly. Unfortunately your answer doesn't help me. My question is how to mix the values of a nested select input AND text input into the same object